# How to add delay to Javascript transition?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

This is my Javascript code -

```
var slideshows = document.querySelectorAll('[data-component="slideshow"]');
slideshows.forEach(initSlideShow);
function initSlideShow(slideshow) {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(`#${slideshow.id} [role="list"] .slide`);
    var index = 0, time = 10000;
    slides[index].classList.add('active');
    setInterval( () => {
        slides[index].classList.remove('active');
        index++;
        if (index === slides.length) index = 0;
        slides[index].classList.add('active');
    }, time);
}
```

This is my markup -

```
<?php foreach( $hero_images as $image_id ): ?>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0.5), rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)), url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );  ?>')">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Example</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have an array of images from Word Press and have them in the background of the parent div.

This is the CSS -

```
[data-component="slideshow"] .slide {
  display: none;
}

[data-component="slideshow"] .slide.active {
  display: block;
}
```

It just toggles the CSS display rule

The code works and the divs transition between display none and display block, but I want the transition to be smoother. I want to add a fade in.

I thought something like this would do it -

```
.slide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

But it does not have any affect.

Is it possible to add a delay to the transition of `display:none` to `display:block`?

Comment: It is not possible to control the transition from display none to some other value. What you can do is either use some other property to accomplish transition. For example, you can use `opacity` property (decent solution for fade in / fade out effects) or `transform: scale()` property (does good job if you desire to gradually increase/decrease content in size).

EDIT: I now see you posted example with opacity. Imho, that should work. Your `.active` selector should be `.slide.active`, not just `.active`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keyframe-animation to controll the timing of your attributes more accurately.

Here is an example of a fadein-animation (onclick) using keyframes:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="testcontainer">

  </div>
</div>

$(".testcontainer").addClass("anim");
$(".outerContainer").on("click",function(){
    $(this).find(".testcontainer").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```js
$(".testcontainer").addClass("anim");
$(".outerContainer").on("click",function(){
    $(this).find(".testcontainer").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.testcontainer{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:green;
  opacity:0;
  display:none;
}
.outerContainer{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:200px;
  width:600px;
}

.outerContainer .testcontainer.active{
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  display:blocK;
  opacity:1;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display:block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="testcontainer">

  </div>
</div>
```

I would still recommend you to use a library like jquery or pure javascript for animations like this, since its alot simpler to implement animations in this way. If you have the creative freedom to choose, of course.